# How to create a Customized JButton which accepts image as an argument?

Tags: java, swing, oop, jbutton, paintcomponent

I am trying to create my own customized Swing button class by extending `JButton` class, whose constructor will accept a string, an image and an icon as arguments and will construct a button having all these arguments. 
With code below i got the output in which the background image actually overlaps the icon and text. How to overcome this?

```
 public class CustomizedButton extends JButton{

     Image i;
     Dimension d;
     public CustomizedButton(String str, ImageIcon icon,Image img) {


     d = new Dimension(1000,500);
     this.setForeground(Color.red);
     this.setText(str);
     this.setIcon(icon);
     this.i = img;  
     this.setPreferredSize(d);

     }

   @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
          super.paintComponent(g);
     g.drawImage(i, 0, 0, null);

   }

 }
```

Comment: Why would the button have both an `Image` and an `ImageIcon`?  BTW - If overriding `paintComponent(Graphics g)` the code should immediately call `super.paintComponent(g)`..  Further, can you be more specific about the type of guidance you need?

Comment: @AndrewThompson, my thought is that the image will act as a background and icon and text will overlay upon the background image of this CustomizedButton.

Comment: OK.. I'm still not clear what your actual question is.  Because if it is *" Can anybody guide me a bit?"* the question is prime to be closed as ..any of a number of reasons.

Comment: @AndrewThompson in simple words.. i want to paint a JButton with an image. Is there any other way to do that than extending AbstractButton class?

Comment: remove this.setUI(new JButton().getUI()); and to override getPreferredSize, use those coordinates (getHeight/Wieght)in paintComponent

Comment: @mKorbel thanks... it worked. I can now see both icon and image and the text i want to be displayed over button.